# IIS using ADFS/Saml to Authenticate

Tags: iis, authentication, adfs

Does anyone know if there is a ADFS/SAML Identity Provider for IIS7?

Example workflow - the user will go to the directory /private and it will redirect to the provider to login and back if the user is authenticated correctly.

I know its possible using forms auth, but I just want to secure 1 directory, seems a bit OTT to write something.

Cheers